# VSCode window cannot be moved when the title bar is not reachable

Tags: windows, windows-11, visual-studio-code, move, screenresolution

Usual Windows applications will open the "Windows menu" an upper-leftmost menu for resizing/moving/closing the window, by typing Alt+Space, which is a lifesaver when the title bar is not accessible.

VScode is using this keyboard shortcut to 
 [image] preempting the availability of the Windows menu.

I work on a laptop at different locations with different external monitors resolutions and sizes, upon restoring the VSCode windows layout at another location the top Windows menu bar may be outside the reachable area.

Is there another way to move the vscode window when the title bar is unreachable ?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to hover the application on the start bar until the preview window appears, right-click that and click 'Move' then use the cursor keys on the keyboard to start moving it.

[image]

You can then use the mouse to move it so it fits.

Comment: Yes, and alt-space works too when hovering on the task bar miniature previews. I have had success with alt-space then M (for move) then one of the arrow keys, then the mouse (no need to click)

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a build-in failsafe.
If part of the window is still visible on screen, just grab a corner to resize it. After the window was resized (even just by one pixel) it will detect that the window title bar is too far off screen to be grabbed, and it will reposition the window such that the title bar is on screen again.

I'm not entirely sure if you can resize from any side, or only the left side though.

Another option is to double-click on the bottom edge. This will resize the window to stretch top to bottom, but keep left and right as they are. This also moves the window back on screen.